# Strong stability of the wave equation with time depending potential

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control, hyperbolic-pde, stability

It is well known that the wave equation with frictional damping 
$$\eqalign{
  & {y_{tt}} = {y_{xx}} - a(t,x){y_t}{\text{  }}{\text{,(t}}{\text{,x)}} \in {\text{ }}(0,\infty ) \times (0,1)  \cr 
  & y(t,0) = y(t,1) = 0 \cr} $$ 
is strongly stable in the energy space $H^1_0 \times L^2$ norm in the case $a(t,x)=a(x)$ if it is non zero everywhere ($a$ is in $L^\infty$).

What can we say about the case $a(t,x)$ ?. Clearly, we can not use the spectral theory here because of the time dpending of $a$. Is there any references or suggestions ?
Thank you.